# Does the close method of ofstream also close the underlying handle

Tags: c++, windows, iostream

On Windows platform, a file handle is got from calling CreateFile, and then the handle is used to initialize an ofstream object. A minimal example is as below:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

class CSV_writer {
public:
    std::ofstream my_ofstream;
private:
    HANDLE my_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    int file_descriptor = -1;
    FILE * my_file = nullptr;   //FILE type is actually a IO buff.
    const static unsigned int fl = 256;
public:
    explicit CSV_writer(const TCHAR * file_name_) {
    //get current directory
    TCHAR current_path[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, current_path);

    TCHAR filename[fl]{ 0 };
    _tcscat_s(filename, file_name_);
    _tcscat_s(filename, _T(".csv"));
    if (current_path[_tcslen(current_path) - 1] != _T('\\') && _tcslen(current_path) < MAX_PATH - 1) {
        _tcscat_s(current_path, _T("\\"));
    }
    else {
        throw std::exception("path length exceeding limit.");
    }

    if (_tcslen(current_path) + _tcslen(filename) + 1 < MAX_PATH) {
        _tcscat_s(current_path, filename);
    }
    else {
        //current path exceeds the max path length defined in MAX_PATH
        throw std::exception("path length exceeding limit.");
    }

    this->my_handle = CreateFile(
        current_path,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,   //access permit, both read and write
        0,          //cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the file or device is closed
        nullptr,    //returned handle can not be inherited by child process
        CREATE_ALWAYS,  //always create a new file, overwrite old one if it exists
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        nullptr
    );

    if (my_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        int file_descriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)my_handle, _O_TEXT);
        if (file_descriptor != -1) {
            this->my_file = _fdopen(file_descriptor, "w");
            if (this->my_file != nullptr) {
                this->my_ofstream = std::ofstream(this->my_file);

            }
        }
    }
}

~CSV_writer() {
    // Closes stream, file, file_descriptor, and file_handle.
    this->my_ofstream.flush();
    this->my_ofstream.close();
    this->my_file = nullptr;
    this->file_descriptor = -1;
    this->my_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CSV_writer csv_writer(L"memory_layout");
    csv_writer.my_ofstream << "Type,\t" << "Size,\t" << "Offset,\t" <<   "Address\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, after calling "my_ofstream.close()" afterwards, will the underlying file handle also released? Or I have to call Windows API CloseHandle() manually after calling close()?

Update: to those who say that there is no constructor of ofstream taking FILE*, actually there is, kind of,[image: see the screen shot below]

Comment: There is a constructor of `std::ofstream` that takes a `FILE*` parameter?

Comment: @Steve I can't find such constructor, not even a Microsoft-specific one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-ofstream-class?view=vs-2017#basic_ofstream

Comment: Unless there is, this question makes no sense because you can't open one that way anyway.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) such that people *can* help you?

Comment: Don't post code as link. Post code as text.

Comment: Although such constructor can be found in code, I fear it may be counted as an undocumented feature which anyone outside MSVC team should not use. Or maybe it's just the doucment being imperfect. Still, you need to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, *as text*.

Comment: @NickyC It might be a MSVC extension, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're already aware that the constructor you are using:

```
std::ofstream(FILE * fp)
```

is a non-standard, undocumented Microsoft extension, unguaranteed even by Microsoft.

In that case, Microsoft does not promise you even that:

```
int fd = ...;
...
FILE * fp = _fdopen(fd, "w");
...
std::osftream ofs(fp);
...
ofs.close();
```

will do `fclose(fp)` - never mind `_close(fd)`.

If however you take it as given that `ofs.close()` *does* `fclose(fp)` - and evidently you do - then Microsoft
does promise you that it will also `_close(fd)`. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fdopen-wfdopen?view=vs-2017)

> Remarks

...

> File descriptors passed into _fdopen are owned by the returned FILE * stream.
>   If _fdopen is successful, **do not call _close on the file descriptor**.
>   **Calling fclose on the returned FILE * also closes the file descriptor**.

(My emphasis.)

Comment: Nice documents digging.  My reasoning is that MS added the extension for a reason, so that one don't need to first close a handle after its created, and then open it using its path just to work with it. I would bet on that the handle is closed after the iostream instance is destroyed.

Comment: @JohnZ.Li I'm that sure it and experiment would confirm it, but personally I still wouldn't let important code rely on an *undocumented* extension.